# Python - get string after specific character from inverse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to capture the domains of these email list. I have sub domains in the email and trying to remove it. I just need a string before and after '.' from backwards

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
emails = ['gmail.com','aol.com','','123.abc.edu','123.er.abc.edu','','abc.gov','test.net']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids,'emails':emails})
df

ids emails
0   1   gmail.com
1   2   aol.com
2   3   
3   4   123.abc.edu
4   5   123.er.abc.edu
5   6   
6   7   abc.gov
7   8   test.net
```

Tried this and combinations of -1, 2:...etc

```
df.emails.str.split(".", 1).str[-1]

0           com
1           com
2              
3       abc.edu
4    er.abc.edu
5              
6           gov
7           net
```

Need output like this one

```
ids emails
0   1   gmail.com
1   2   aol.com
2   3   
3   4   abc.edu
4   5   abc.edu
5   6   
6   7   abc.gov
7   8   test.net
```

Comment: Why did you pass 1 as the second argument to `split`?

Comment: So... if `.` is only present only once - keep the original - otherwise - keep everything after it the first `.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing `1` as the second argument to `split()` you limit the split to one.

Use instead:

```py
df.emails.str.split(".").str[-2:]
```

to obtain the last two segments of the split string:

```
0    [gmail, com]
1      [aol, com]
2              []
3      [abc, edu]
4      [abc, edu]
5              []
6      [abc, gov]
7     [test, net]
```

To get the output as a string including the dot, chain a method to join the previous output:

```py
In []: df.emails.str.split(".").str[-2:].str.join(".")
Out[]: 
0    gmail.com
1      aol.com
2             
3      abc.edu
4      abc.edu
5             
6      abc.gov
7     test.net
Name: emails, dtype: object
```

Comment: It looks like the OP is expecting `er.abc.edu` from index 4 instead of `abc.edu`

Comment: One might also be able to get away with something like: `df.emails.str.extract(r'(\w+\.\w+$)')`

Comment: @JonClements I think you mistook the pentultimate codebox in the OP for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.emails.str.split(".").str[-2:].str.join(sep='.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pre process emails list

```
emails = ['gmail.com','aol.com','','123.abc.edu','123.er.abc.edu','','abc.gov','test.net']

emails_filtered = []
for email in emails:
    if '.' in email:
        emails_filtered.append( '.'.join( [ email.split('.')[:-2] ] ) )
    else:
        emails_filtered.append('')

df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids,'emails':emails_filtered})
```

hope it helps.